# Tableview reloading with new data only after the second call

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview with a searchbar that should load data into cells while typing in the searchbar. My code does load the data like it should using a function with a callback. Printing the data to the console shows the correct search results, but after the reloadData method is called the cells don't refresh. When another character is typed and it loads new data, the tableview refreshes with the data from the previous request.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _teams.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TeamCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    TeamModel *team = _teams[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = team.name;

    return cell;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"%@", searchText);

    poolDataHandler = [[PoolDataHandler alloc] init];
    [poolDataHandler GetTeams:searchText completion:^(NSArray *tempteams) {
        _teams = tempteams;
        NSLog(@"%@", _teams);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Note that I'm using model classes to parse the JSON results.

Also, it seems that the row count does update, for it crashes when the results are less than in the previous query. Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
When I cancel the search it does refresh with the initial results. I must be missing something fundamental...

Comment: What thread is the completion block called on?

Comment: i think table reload should be outside the block because on every character input/ou this method get called to update your array

Comment: It requests data from a server, so it's called asynchronously if that answers your question

Comment: @AashishJoshi it's supposed to update the table everytime a character is entered. If this is bad practice do let me know :-)

Comment: Like Wain suggested, this is probably related to reloading tableView data on background thread. Just change [self.tableView reloadData] to: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData]; });

Comment: @user1873508 ah that makes sense. Your suggestion however doesn't seem to refresh the table either

Comment: Second problem here: You are assigning _teams variable with new data inside a block. Did you specified your instance variable to be editable in blocks? Like:  property (nonatomic, strong) __block NSArray *teams;  ?

Comment: I see you are accessing ivars directly so instead of using property, you can just use    __block NSArray *_teams;

Comment: The concept of having different threads is very new to me.. If I can access these ivars from the callback, why would I not be able to use them to reload my table? And why does it refresh with the previous received data the second time it is called? I have a feeling it has something to do with either the way searchbars work (it refreshes the table after pressing 'cancel' on the searchbar as well) or the way I set everything up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I didn't know the Search Bar And Search Display had its own tableview... the following worked for me, using the default reload function, setting it to not reload immediately and then manually reload the correct tableview in the callback:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller         shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchText {
    poolDataHandler = [[PoolDataHandler alloc] init];
    [poolDataHandler GetTeams:searchText completion:^(NSArray *tempteams) {
        _teams = tempteams;
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }];

    return NO;
}
```